# How to load js file based on variable?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I am going to rewrite my website in i18n, so I use template engine in angular.js to help me load different language, following code is to load different language file, but I got the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL", why and how to load my language file?

```
        if(lang!='en-US')
        {
            document.write('<script src="lang/'+lang+'.js"></script>');
        }
        else
        {
            document.write('<script src="lang/en-US.js"></script>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the script.

```
document.write('<script src="lang/'+lang+'.js"></script>');
                                                   |
                                                   +--- Here script get closed
```

Use something like:

```
document.write('<script src="lang/' + lang + '.js"><' + '/script>');
```

or better:

```
document.write('\x3Cscript src="lang/' + lang + '.js">\x3C/script>');
```